# Angular 4 - ngForm values sometime persist after deleting ngModel values while using template validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I've made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ki375ObWqTqW8RYfLjsB) where the issue can be easily recreated. Simply add a few fields and quickly delete them.

I'm aware that using reactivate forms is probably the way to go here, this is what I plan to do. It does buy you a lot more than using template validation. However, I'm still curious about how to solve this issue.

I have a array feeding a table on my template, I can add many records and I can only remove them slowly to avoid form validation issues. If I try to quickly remove records by using this method.

```
clickRemove(index: number) {
    this.testFields.splice(index, 1);
}
```

It will delete my records from the testFields array, but SOMETIMES it will not delete them from my ngForm myForm.value. This will cause my submit field to be disabled as it's failing the !myForm.form.valid check.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid || testFields.length == 0">Submit</button>
```

You can't pass the form values and delete them. When I try this I get the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property value of # which has only a getter'.

Comment: Can you check this https://plnkr.co/edit/LJzQxRguzF62qh3witNq?p=preview? Does the issue still remain?

Comment: yes it does! @yurzui thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments by @yurzui. It really helped me understand and put this together. I needed to add a trackBy function to my *ngFor loop to keep track of the changes on all objects.

Template edit.

```
<tr *ngFor="let testField of testFields; trackBy: trackByFn; index as i;">
```

Added this function to my component.

```
trackByFn(index: number) {
          return index;
        }
```